# How to make a 3 column matrix with Flight number, Start index and End index

Tags: matlab

[image: an idea of how i would like to divide my flight numbers in blue]

Just looking at the top graph (which represents the lift force of a certain object). I would like to obtain a Nx3 matrix with flight number, start index and end index respectively.

M11 is the moving mean line and I tried coding it so that it would only start the flight when M11 hits -8.75. Im kinda new to matlab and coding so help would be appreciated.

```
i=1:end;
if M11(i) > -8.75
flag on;
flightnumberx start;
check next movmean;

M11(i) < -8.75
flag off;
flightnumberx end;
x=x+1;
check next movemean;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data of the Nx3 matrix as single vectors you can just use this to get it into a matrix

```
newMatrix = (vector1  vector2  vector3);
```

If you are trying to extract points first you can use a for loop to go through all the data points, then if (condition M11(i) > -8.75), yourVector =[yourVector ; newPoint];

you would need to do this for all the vectors and when you are creating the matrix make sure your vectors are the same length (you can check with size(vectorToCheck);)

matrix operations are explained here: [matlab link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html)